# Errors with using Scalaxb for code generation

Tags: web-services, scala, soap, wsdl, scalaxb

I had to fiddle with a WSDL document for one of the implementations and I came across Scalaxb! I'm now trying to generate some scala classes from the WSDL file that I have and as expected I'm hitting into some issues:

Here is a snippet of the WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:tns="http://www.myservice.com/MyServices/2012/06/18/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
 xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 name="MyServices"
 targetNamespace="http://www.myservice.com/MyServices/2012/06/18/">
<wsdl:types>
 <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.myservice.com/MyServices/2012/06/18/">
  <s:complexType name="UserCredentials">
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="UserName" type="s:string" />
    <s:element name="Password" type="s:string" />
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  <s:element name="UserCredentials" type="tns:UserCredentials" />
  <s:complexType name="AnotherComplexType" >
   <s:sequence>
    <s:element name="Index" type="s:int" />
    <s:element name="Name" type="s:string" />
    <s:element name="Status" type="s:boolean" />
   </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  ....
```

Assume that the rest of the WSDL file is completely fine, when I tried to compile the project, I hit the following error:

```
[error] /Users/joe/Desktop/scalaxb-soap-example/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-scalaxb/myservice/xmlprotocol.scala:1542: not found: value userCredentials
[error]             scalaxb.toXML(userCredentials, Some("http://www.myservice.com/MyServices/2012/06/18/"), "UserCredentials", defaultScope), defaultScope, baseAddress, "POST", Some(new java.net.URI("http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?WebService=SetGPTimerChannel"))).transform({ case (header, body) => 
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/joe/Desktop/scalaxb-soap-example/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-scalaxb/myservice/xmlprotocol.scala:1544: value toSeq is not a member of Any
[error]               scala.xml.Elem(null, "Body", scala.xml.Null, defaultScope, true, body.toSeq: _*)
[error]                                                                                     ^
[error] /Users/joe/Desktop/scalaxb-soap-example/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-scalaxb/myservice/xmlprotocol.scala:1551: not found: value userCredentials
[error]             scalaxb.toXML(userCredentials, Some("http://www.myservice.com/MyServices/2012/06/18/"), "UserCredentials", defaultScope), defaultScope, baseAddress, "POST", Some(new java.net.URI("http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi?WebService=SomeServiceCall"))).transform({ case (header, body) => 
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/joe/Desktop/scalaxb-soap-example/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/sbt-scalaxb/myservice/xmlprotocol.scala:1553: value toSeq is not a member of Any
[error]               scala.xml.Elem(null, "Body", scala.xml.Null, defaultScope, true, body.toSeq: _*)
[error]                                                                                     ^
```

Any ideas what and why I'm facing this issue?  Here is my build.sbt:

```
import ScalaxbKeys._

val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.2"
val scalaParser = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.1"
val dispatchV = "0.11.1" // change this to appropriate dispatch version
val dispatch = "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % dispatchV

organization := "com.eon"

name := "scalaxb-myservice-sample"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

scalaxbSettings

packageName in (Compile, scalaxb) := "rdmservice"

dispatchVersion in (Compile, scalaxb) := dispatchV

async in (Compile, scalaxb) := true

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= scalaxb in Compile

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaXml, scalaParser, dispatch)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated source? Presumably you 'fiddled' with the userCredentials object. Can you find it defined anywhere? It looks like it should be capitalised.

Comment: No! it is not to be found defined anywhere! But it is being generated, so I do not have any control of it being in capital letters!

Comment: Are all the other types being generated ok? Are there any warnings/errors generated by scalaxb?

Comment: No there are no warnings or what-so-ever!

Comment: And are all the other types being generated? If so, it's very weird. I'd submit a bug report with a link to the wsdl.

Comment: I just did submit a issue yesterday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to generate WSDL client code, using `scalaxb` might be a bit too much. As an option, you could just use `wsimport` wrapped as a simple SBT task that would be executed before the main code compilation. Apart from one less dependency, it also keeps  your repository pristine and frees it from committing the generated boilerplate Java code. Here's a sample template project if anyone is interested: https://github.com/sainnr/sbt-scala-wsdl-template.